# Rails has_one and belongs_to migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, belongs-to, has-one

I'm trying to establish a relationship between two models in Rails but I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do in my migration. Any help is much appreciated.

I want each business to have a type/category such as "Automotive", or "Restaurant and Bar".

Business.rb:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category, :foreign_key => "cid"
  attr_accessible :description, :email, :facebook, :foursquare, :google, :manager,
  :mobile, :name, :phone, :url, :yelp
end
```

Type.rb:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cid, :category
  belongs_to :business
end
```

CreateTypes migration file:

```
class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :types do |t|
      t.integer :cid
      t.string :category
      t.references :business

      t.timestamps
    end
  add_index :types, :cid
 end
end
```

CreateBusinesses migration file:

```
class CreateBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :businesses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
      t.string :phone
      t.string :manager
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :mobile
      t.boolean :foursquare
      t.boolean :facebook
      t.boolean :yelp
      t.boolean :google
      t.text :description
      t.integer :cid

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easiest for you to keep with rails naming conventions. If I got it correctly, a business belongs to a Type/Category. let the business reference the type. add a belongs_to on the business side and a has_many on the type/category side. Roughly like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :email, :facebook, :foursquare, :google, :manager, :mobile, :name, :phone, :type_id, :url, :yelp
  belongs_to :type
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
end

class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :types do |t|
      t.string :category

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :businesses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
      t.string :phone
      t.string :manager
      t.string :email
      t.boolean :mobile
      t.boolean :foursquare
      t.boolean :facebook
      t.boolean :yelp
      t.boolean :google
      t.text :description
      t.integer :type_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I redid the migration, but I should add `attr_accessible  :category` to my Type model so that I can create categories, right?

Comment: after you define the models and migrate your database you can simply run rails c and try to create the models and associations:  t = Type.create; b = t.businesses.create; b.type == t

Comment: in case you want to use mass assignment then you should add the attr_accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your `businesses` table must have integer field `cid`, because it you set it as a foreign key. You `types` table must not have `cid` field. The `types.id` field will be used to create a relationship. Note that `belongs_to` method doesn't have `foreign_key` option, you should remove it from its call.

I can advise you not to change foreign key name without a reason. If you don't specify foreign key, it defaults to `type_id`.

Comment: I somewhat understand what you are saying. I will edit my original post, reflecting the changes to my files. I still not 100% clear though, so I would appreciate any further elaboration.

Comment: I don't have an error, but how can I check that the association is working?